# Folding commented sections in Texstudio 2.6.6

Tags: texstudio, comments, code-folding

I want to know, if and how can I apply code folding to commented out sections in Texstudio 2.6.6?

Comment: How did you comment out the sections? Using a length list of `%`s?

Comment: yes . by puttting '%' sign at beginning of lines to be commented.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've commented out the `\section` command, it is not recognized as such anymore and thus cannot be folded. However, you can insert a special comment to mark a part of the file as foldable like this:

```
%BEGIN_FOLD
%\section{My Section}
%The text.
%END_FOLD
```